# How do you change the position of some text in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am programming an antivirus and really need to know how to change the position of the text that says "Infected!" and "Clean!"

I have not really tried much, because I took a tutorial on how to make it. I do not know how to program in Visual Basic. Sorry I know I'm a noob. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        txtFilePath.Text = path

        Dim sample As String
        sample = md5_hash(path)
        txtHash.Text = md5_hash(path)

        Using f As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("md5.txt")
            Using s As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(f)
                While Not s.EndOfStream
                    Dim line As String = s.ReadLine

                    If (line = sample) Then
                        lblResult.Text = "Infected!"
                        lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    Else
                        lblResult.Text = "Clean!"
                        lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

This is only a piece of the code. Please tell me how to fix this. I really could use some help. Thank You!

Comment: What does "change the position" mean? Open snipping tool, screenshot your app, use the pen to draw an arrow from where the text is now, to where you want it to be, press Ctrl-C, come to edit your question, press Ctrl-V, accept automatic imgur upload :)

Comment: The text is displayed in the `Label`.  If you want to change the position of the text then you change the `Location` of the `Label`.  That said, while it's far from unheard of, you generally don't move controls around on the form.  Maybe you should have more than one `Label` or maybe you should set the `Location` correctly at design time.  We don't know what the appropriate solution is because you have provided an inadequate description of the problem.  ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation, which includes not just what you're trying to achieve, but also why you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: Please only add relevant tags: your question is not about anti-virus software (it's irrelevant to your question that you're trying to make an anti-virus application), it's about text on a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to change the LOCATION of a label, use  the

```
lblresult.Location = new Point(xCoord here, yCoord here)
```

Another way to adjust the position would be with the

```
lblresult.Top += How much you want it to be pushed down/up from its origin
```

Same is with the

```
lblresult.Right
lblresult.Left
lblresult.Bottom
```

Parameters. I think you should give more clear and detailed information about what you are trying to achieve and how one could help you